# ¿Cómo recuperar instalación de Oracle en la que sólo quedaron los archivos de datos?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

Tengo el siguiente problema: Había instalado una base de datos Oracle 12c con Oracle Linux 6.8 en un servidor con un storage.

El Linux estaba instalado en los discos internos del servidor, al igual que los binarios de Oracle.
La base de datos estaba en el storage.

Por motivos de logística, y al no usarse más esta base de datos, se instaló un VMWare Center y por consiguiente se perdieron el sistema operativo Linux y los binarios de Oracle.

Ahora me surgió la necesidad de volver a instalar la base de datos, pero no tengo backups. Y en el storage han que quedado dos puntos de montaje: ORADATA y ORAFRA.

¿Es posible volver a instalar los binarios y hacer que Oracle tome los datos que quedaron grabados en el storage?

Desde ya, agradezco su atención.

Comment: que yo sepa no, para eso son los backup's

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.